# Hitting enter (return) key on a form with multiple submit buttons

Tags: html, forms

If there are multiple submit buttons on a form,which submit button is triggered when user hits enter key in a `input type="text"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML Standard (inplicit submission):

> A form element's default button is the first submit button in tree
>   order whose form owner is that form element.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#implicit-submission

Give it a try:

```
    <form>
    <input type='text'>
        <input onclick="alert('FIRST')" type="submit" value="FIRST" />
        <input onclick="alert('SECOND')" type="submit" value="SECOND" />
    </form>
```

It should be first `type="submit"` input.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/5tmwjdad/

Comment: well I tried that but what I really wanted to know was that is it the same on all browsers? like a rule?